# Calling `sleep` or `pause` in karma scenario for angular app breaks framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I have an angular app that uses `$routeProvider` to load different partials into an `ng-view`.

So, in my e2e scenarios, when I call `browser().navigateTo('/')`, I also need to call `sleep(0.5)` or something to wait for the elements to actually appear.

Unfortunately, calling `sleep` totally breaks the testing!  All of a sudden the framework behaves as if it cannot see the page at all, and can never find elements.

My e2e tests in which I don't have to wait for anything to load can find all the elements I expect, but if I put a sleep call in those tests anyway, then they break as well.

Does anyone have a suggestion for what to look at?  Some way to increase the verbosity of the console?  Some way to snap the tester back into focus?

Additional info:

- There is no error output in the browser console or on the command line console!
- I have copied my karma setup directly out of the angular-seed project.  As far as I can tell they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) for your Angular E2E tests. This has awareness of angular and returns promises. You could do something like this then:

```
ptor.get('http://localhost/#/my-route').then(function () {
  // Do something
});
```

You can also use `ptor.wait` like this:

```
    var timeout = 10000;

    ptor.wait(function () {
      return {some condition}
    }, timeout);
```

Which will wait for a condition to be true before moving on.

Also you can use `ptor.waitForAngular()` which will wait for angular to resolve any promises and http requests.